# sendgridを利用したお問い合わせがvercelにデプロイすると送信されない

Tags: reactjs, next.js

ローカルではメールが届いているが、デプロイして本番にあげた途端届かない事象が起きました。

vercelのログを見ると200は返してるので送信自体は成功しているっぽい。けど実際にメールが届かない...

sendgridのActivity見ても反映されていない...basic認証かけてたせいかと思ったけど無くしても意味なく...

同じ現象に遭遇した方いませんか？

一応参考にしたサイト
https://zenn.dev/aono/articles/fc4fa8863134ac

Comment: https://software.pitang1965.com/2022/01/16/sending-email-with-nextjs-and-sendgrid/の内容に変えたら送られたから単純にコードが良くなかったっぽい、でもローカルはOKでvercelの環境ダメってなんでしょね？

Comment: 現状、何を聞きたいのか、どのような設定・ソースコードなのかの情報が一切ないため、回答は得られなさそうです。[良い質問をするには](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) を参考に、補足情報を追加してみてください。